# When I call the balanceOf function for a contract and specify a block number in call(), I receive a forbidden URL error

Tags: web3py

When I use `contract.functions.balanceOf(wallet_address).call(block_identifier=block_num)` I get a forbidden URL error, but if I run the same call without using the `block_identifier` argument, it works as expected. What is the reason that this is happening?